# Wonderware Intouch Alarms - Filter on Single Tag in ActiveX AlarmViewerCtrl

Tags: wonderware

I need to filter/query a single tag in the AlarmViewerCtrl ActiveX object. I know that I can create Query Favorites but my requirement is to dynamically (at runtime) filter a specific Tag Name(s) to display in the ActiveX Alarm object.

Ultimately what I need is a way to force (maybe SQL injection??) the AlarmViewerCtrl to use a custom (runtime) Select statement such as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [WWALMDB].[dbo].[v_AlarmHistory]
  WHERE TagName Like 'M_100%'
```

Comment: Not exactly what you were looking for, but you could put your alarms in their own Alarm Group (likely a subgroup of whatever you're currently using) and just use the Query Favorites. I've used a custom DataGridView control to do specific alarm queries in the past but it comes with its own usability challenges to do it that way.